# update value in database on button click, using a dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, submit

I am getting the users via $wpdb (wordpress function), then I display the values id,name and mg_nobility in a table that has a dropdown menu to select the nobility and a submit button. how can I get the id of the row that correspond to the clicked submit button so I can update the mg_nobility in the database?

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users" );
?>
<form method="post">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Nobility</th>
    <th>Select Nobility</th>
    <th>Submit</th>
  </tr>
<?php 
foreach ($results as $key ) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($key as $row=>$value ) {

    if ($row == "ID" ) {
      echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }elseif ($row == "display_name") {
      echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }elseif ($row == "mg_nobility") {
      echo "<td>$value</td>
      <td>
       <select name='nobility_value'>
        <option value='nobilityOne'>nobility One</option>
        <option value='nobilityTwo'>nobility Two</option>
        <option value='nobilityThree'>nobility Three</option>
        <option value='nobilityFour'>nobility Four</option>
       </select>
      </td> 
      <td><button type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button></td>";
    }
  }
  echo "</tr>"; 
}?>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
   $nobility = $_POST['nobility_value'];
  # wordpress query....
}
?>
```

var_dump of the $results look similar to this:

```
array(6) { 
 [0]=> object(stdClass)#3359 (11) { 
       ["ID"]=> string(1) "1"  
       ["user_login"]=> string(9) "Daniel" 
       ["user_pass"]=> string(34)"$P$Bph9BrPkxjPzgAGhjv0" 
       ["user_nicename"]=> string(9) "daniel" 
       ["user_email"]=> string(14) "declst@gmail" 
       ["user_url"]=> string(0) ...........etc...}
       } 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#3360 (11) {
       ["ID"]=> string(1) "6" 
       ["user_login"]=> string(9) "dwa3" 
       ["user_pass"]=> string(34) "$P$Bi9upVUk.dxZ7wkK83mbcU."
       .......etc.....}
```

Comment: What does `$results` look like?

Comment: I left an example above

Answer (score 0):

You can add *name* and *value* attributes to each button, something like `name="ID"` `value="$idvalue"`. They will be submitted with the form data. Read the [MDN doc on `<button>` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).